# OpenID Discovery URL list

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I use DotNetOpenAuth in my Asp.Net application.

I want to create a login page where user can choose among most common OpenID providers like google, yahoo...

I'd like to have image buttons like SO login.

1) Is there a best practice to achieve this? (Like a free/open asp.net control)

2) Do you have a list of common Discovery URLS?

- https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id (google)
- https://me.yahoo.com (yahoo)
- ...

**update**

Just for info I've found also this:

- [socialauth-net](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/)

Comment: I assume you mean "I want to create a login page where the user can choose among the most common OpenID providers like google, yahoo, etc."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for: http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/OpenIdFormsAuth.aspx) which shows how to do OpenID Authentication using ASP.NET/MVC. If you are not using MVC, then [check out this page (see cautionary comment below)](http://madskristensen.net/post/OpenID-implementation-in-Csharp-and-ASPNET.aspx), which shows how to do it in C#/ASP.NET without any MVC.

Also check out [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) and [Stacky](http://stacky.codeplex.com/) which help you implement some of the Stack Overflow type stuff in .NET.

Finally, if you need a list of providers/discovery list, check [out this list!](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev.OpenIDProviderList)

Comment: Be *very* cautious about the link to madskristensen's web site.  It portrays a "simple" OpenID that has massive security holes (thus his disclaimer at the top of his post).